# ¿Como almacenar los valores de los controles de un Fragment con viewpager?

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

ya implemente varias cosas y sencillamente no encuentro como, bueno paso al grano:
 tengo varios fragments que los despliego con el viewpager, deseo guardar los datos que hay en los controles del fragment, para esto tengo una funcion en el fragment para que se guarden, para ese proposito cree la funcion updateCaja();

```
public class Fragment_Caja1 extends Fragment {
public Fragment_Caja1() {
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_caja1, container, false);

    edt_caja1 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edt_caja1);

    return v;
}


public void updateCaja(int _id){
    ContentValues val = new ContentValues();
    val.put("caja1", caja1.getText().toString);
    SQLiteDatabase db = getActivity().openOrCreateDatabase("Caja", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.update("Caja",uEnc,"_id="+_id, null);
    db.close();
  }
}
```

añado el codigo de mi activity principal:

```
public class Activity_Caja extends AppCompatActivity implements Comunicador{

int id_tabla_caja1;

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.clear();
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_encuesta, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.opc_guardar:
            actualiza(id_tabla_caja1);
            return true;
        case R.id.opc_cancelar:
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lineabase);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tb_lin_bas);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
}


private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment_Caja1(), "Caja1");
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment_Caja2(), "Caja2"));

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}


@Override
public void actualiza(int id) {

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment_Caja1 f_c1 = (Fragment_Caja1 fm.findFragmentById(R.layout.fragment_caja1);

    f_c1.updateEncuesta(id);
}


class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
  }
}
```

uso una interface:

```
public interface Comunicador {

public void actualiza(int id);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si entendi tu pregunta lo primero que debes hacer es que los fragment retengan la informacion en el viewpager y luego debes obtene las intancias de dichos fragments en tu caso seria algo asi.

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2); // Esto es para que se retenga la informacion de los dos fragment funciona perfecto
```

ahora para obtener un fragment dentro de un "FragmentPagerAdapter"

```
Fragment_Caja1 f_c1;
Fragment_Caja2 f_c2;

if(adapter.getItem(0)!=null) {
  f_c1 = (Fragment_Caja1) adapter.getItem(0);
}

if(adapter.getItem(1)!=null) {
  f_c2 = (Fragment_Caja2) adapter.getItem(1);
}
```

Ahora ya retienes la informacion y tienes los dos fragments del viewpager para manipularlos y ahora si puedes hacer facil por que ya tienes las intancias de los fragment que estan dentro del viewpager.

```
f_c1.updateCaja(id);
f_c2.updateCaja(id);
```

Comment: con una ligera modificacion pero si funciono muchas gracias.....

Comment: de nada para eso estamos :D.

Comment: amigo cuando roto la pantalla y guardo me marcar este error Attempt to invoke virtual method